# How to check system config field value before used in front end in Magetno 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend, backend, system.xml, system-config

I need to check the config field value before they used in fronted at any where 
Suppose 
Ex. customform/general/adminmail, the field i used in many extension so i am check that value befor they used in front end

[image]

I add that checking value from front and in system config like as mention in picture.

Answer (score 0):

Defaults are usually set in etc/config.xml. You can find it in this file config.xml